# Change certain values in a dataframe column based on conditions on several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, where-clause

Let's take this sample dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','B','B','B','A'], 'Subcategory':['C','C','E','D','D']})

  Category Subcategory
0        A           C
1        B           C
2        B           E
3        B           D
4        A           D
```

I would like to replace the "B" values in Category by "B2" where there is a C or a D in Subcategory. I tried the following but I get the error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()" :

```
df['Category']=np.where((df['Category']=='B') and (df['Subcategory']=='C' or df['Subcategory']== 'D'),'B2',df['Category'])
```

I know that some similar questions are already asked on Stackoverflow but I can't figure out where I am wrong. Could you please help me to understand my error ?

Expected output :

```
  Category Subcategory
0        A           C
1       B2           C
2        B           E
3       B2           D
4        A           D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bitwise operator and brackets with every conditions. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388950/logical-or-bitwise-or-in-pandas-data-frame) for explanation

```
df['Category']=np.where((df['Category']=='B')
                        & ((df['Subcategory']=='C')
                           | (df['Subcategory']== 'D')),'B2',df['Category'])
df

Category    Subcategory
0   A   C
1   B2  C
2   B   E
3   B2  D
4   A   D
```

And better to use `isin` to check multiple values, `df["Subcategory"].isin(['C', 'D'])`

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.loc`. Also you can use `df[column].isin` for multiple values.

```
df.loc[(df["Subcategory"].isin(['C','D'])) & (df["Category"]=='B'),'Category']="B2"
```

Output

```
df
  Category Subcategory
0        A           C
1        B           C
2        B           E
3        B           D
4        A           D
df.loc[(df["Subcategory"].isin(['C', 'D'])) & (df["Category"] == 'B'), 'Category'] = "B2"
df
  Category Subcategory
0        A           C
1       B2           C
2        B           E
3       B2           D
4        A           D
```